# Laravel paginate() not working when passed a big number

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I want to implement `paginate()` function with 100k records. For that I'm using below code:

```
$user_obj = new User();
$users = $user_obj->paginate(100000);
```

But this code is not working but it's working when I pass 10 thousand or another number. I have more than 300k records in my table. I am using `get()` method to fetch all data the `get()` function is also not working.
The page is not working after executing this code, it's throwing below error

> This page isn’t working 
>   localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

[image]

Comment: How many records does this table have?

Comment: Issue nothing live development side, as the error *ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE* means no data received is occurring may be because of the internet connection OR your browser issue. check it.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I am working on localhost and for less number, it's working. It's working for up to 60 thousand but for 1 lac it's not working

Comment: @Jerodev I've more than 3 lac records in a table

Comment: what laravel version you are using?

Comment: @Shiro I am using version 5.0

Comment: I look into the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination, try change your code to `$user_obj = User::paginate(100000);` see working or not

Comment: @Shiro Thanks but it's not working. Now I am clear with actual problem that was because of memory limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occur due to your request our php `max_execution_time` or `memory_limit` so you can set unlimited memory using ini option.
Something like this

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1); //-1 is unlimited
```

But using this option some time may be your server is down due to heavy load so be careful before using it